# What simulator resolution should I use when developing app for Samsung galaxy s2 and galaxy s3?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation, samsung-mobile

From what I found, Samsung galaxy s2 has 480x800 resolution and s3 has 1280x720 resolution. So I believe I should ask my graphics designer to provide me `hdpi` graphics that contain 480x800 background images and to implement same background image in galaxy s3 mobile. Can I use image of size 1280x720 and put it in `xhdpi` folder so that it can work on s3.

The background image is something which covers whole available area for mobile app. so am I right in this approach ??

Comment: it depends that u r setting background to whom.

Comment: if u r setting background to parent layout than its going to cover all part of the screen

Comment: yes setting background to parent layout but what I am asking what graphics size or image size should be used to develop on these two phones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read Supporting multiple screens. You must define dpi on your emulator. 240 is hdpi, 160 is mdpi and below that are usually ldpi.

Extract from Android Developer Guide link above:

320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

Comment: this is what I am looking for start up application. Notice, 240 dp is default for a typical phone screen but 320 dp should be used to hit the maximum possible android phones.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't design in both resolutions?
See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for more detailed.